# Specs on a vintage diode vs modern equivalent

Tags: diodes

a bit of a novice here, but learning.
I am trying to find a replacement for a Hitachi 1SS84 diode, which is no longer manufactured.
The specs are here:
https://pdf.dzsc.com/88889/22732.pdf

[image: Hitachi 1SS84]

The 1N4148 is seen as a replacement.
However, if I look at the specs for those, I am met with different values.
Like these:
https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-discretes/diodes-rectifiers/small-signal-diodes?diode-mounting=through-hole&product-range=1n4148&range=inc-in-stock

The forward V max available is 1V, not 0.8V. Peak reverse voltage is 100V, there is the recovery time. Some things are not listed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You choose a replacement based on the circuit it is used in.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible none of those numbers are particularly important, and a look at the application schematic might clear that up, but if I was totally uninformed of the circuit design, lacked knowledge of the operating principles and had to pick something, the Vishay, Onsemi etc. [BAV19](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85543/bav17.pdf) is very close including the sluggish recovery time (suggesting a lack of gold doping compared to the ubiquitous 1N4148).

If that doesn't work as a drop-in, chances are it also might not work with another randomly picked sample of 1SS84.

Added schematic with presumed diodes:

[image]

I don't think those two diodes are particularly critical, 1N4148 should  work there.

Comment: It is for a power board on a synthesizer. Here is the schematic of the Korg M1 if it helps.:
The diode is used on the KLM 1267 power board (also on other boards). Page 10: https://www.synthxl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/korg-m1-service-manual.pdf

Comment: I see. I will get hold of the 1N4148 diode with the closest specifications to the 1SS84 then.